# remove all repeating elements, which I choose with reduce

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how I could eliminate all the repeated elements that I give it, using reduce

Example:

Input:

```
[1,2,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7]
5
```

Output:

```
[1,2,4,6,6,7,7,7,7]
```

Code:

```
const num = 5
const arr = [1,2,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7]
arr.reduce( (numberToDel) => {
       ...
})
```

Comment: this is unclear, `6` and `7` are also repeated

Comment: I want to send you the value that it removes, it will only be removed how many times is it repeated @MisterJojo

Comment: So the 5 in the input, and the const num = 5 @MisterJojo

Comment: so, if the value is not repeated, it stay in the array ?

Comment: If I don't send that value to the array, it remains even if it is repeated, but if I send it, I want it to delete all with the same value, even if there is only one I want it to delete @MisterJojo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**In any case, `num` can't be an argument in array.reduce().**

If you absolutely want to resolve that  with a array.reduce() method,
but prefer to use array.filter() method.
both create a new array

```js
const
  num  = 5
, arr1 = [1,2,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7]
, arr2 = arr1.reduce((a,c)=>
  {
  if ( c != num) a.push(c)
  return a
  },[])
  
console.log(JSON.stringify( arr2 ))
```

in "old" JavaScript this look like:

```js
var num  = 5
var arr1 = [1,2,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7]

var arr2 = arr1.reduce( myReduce, [] )

function myReduce( accumulator, currentValue )
  {
  if ( currentValue != num) accumulator.push( currentValue )
  return accumulator
  }

console.log(JSON.stringify( arr2 ))
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation